# Java Program skips over user input using the Scanner class and print statements

Tags: java

I have never encountered a problem of this sort before, but three of my latest projects are all having this same problem where, for some reason, Java is skipping over the user's input. Whatever help is offered would be much appreciated!

Note: Just to give some background for this problem, the program is supposed to run a game in a do-while loop. After the first round is complete, the purpose of these lines of code is to allow the user to play more rounds of the game. It stores the user's input in a String and then takes the first character. If the character is 'y' or 'Y', then another round will begin. If the character is not either 'y' or 'Y', the program will end.

```
int iterations = 0;
do{
    System.out.println(result + " Would you like to play again:");
    String strHolder = keyboard.nextLine();
    char repeatOption = strHolder.charAt(0);
    iterations++;
} while(repeatOption == 'y' || repeatOption == 'Y');
```

So the game itself runs fine, but when I get to this part of the program that asks the user if he would like to play again, this happens in my terminal:

```
Would you like to play again:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
```

So, as you can see, the program skips over user input, and there is no "first character" to set the char repeatOption. Again, thanks for taking the time to read this problem, and any support would be much appreciated.

Comment: what will happen if you will paste keyboard.nextLine(); before 
    String strHolder = keyboard.nextLine();

Comment: Maybe, before `char repeatOption = strHolder.charAt(0)`, keep asking until the user enters a non-empty input? e.g. `while (!strHolder.isEmpty()) {strHolder = keyboard.nextLine(); }`

Comment: Is `keyboard` being used for something else before the loop? Perhaps with a `nextInt`?

Comment: This is happening because `strHolder` has no character at index 0. It's an empty string left over in the keyboard buffer from some earlier input. One way to go forward is put the prompt and keyboard.nextLine() inside another loop that ignores empty string inputs.

Comment: I suggest you try replacing `keyboard.nextLine()` with `keyboard.next()`

Comment: Thanks @Oskar, this fixes the problem! But I'm wondering why? Does the 'keyboard.nextLine' just clear whatever was stored in the object 'keyboard' before these lines?

Comment: @KenOn10, this works! What is the difference between the Scanner class's next() and nextLine() methods, and how does this cause the fix? I know that the nextLine() method is used with String inputs, but I've never encountered the next() class before.

Comment: The problem is very likely that *before* that code, some user input is read and processed using `next()` (or similar), without consuming the line break. So this time, the line break from the previous input is processed, yielding an empty line.

Comment: @TobyTuck, `next()` returns the next token, doesn't need a line break.  I think Holger's thoughts are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scanner buffer was not empty (probably new line char was there) and when your programme was trying to get input from user, scanner was insntly getting value from buffer and nextLine() method did not return anything.

Possible solutions:

- change nextLine() to other method that not consume the new line char (\n)
- flush the buffer before getting value from user